# Grails 2.0.1 controller action methods have stopped working

Tags: grails

My project has always used grails 2.0.1 and my controllers define their actions as methods not closures. Previously these actions have always worked (i.e. the browser can render the correct gsp page first going through the action method in the controller).

Recently we've noticed that the bespoke actions no longer work, the browser reports a '404 resource not found'. We're still on grails 2.0.1, this is confirmed by 'loading grails 2.0.1' comments in every grails command that is run. Although there are some controller/domain/services changes, none of those changes should affect the use of action methods. From what I can tell, we've not downgrade the version of grails/groovy.

If I change the actions to be defined as closures, then it works fine. But I'm not happy with this as my solution as methods are the preferred way and it used to work.

I've tried the usual approach to grails weirdness: proper clean and rebuild, but no joy. Also, this is an issue in both eclipse and unix envs (project delivered as a war run by the grails command), so it must be something in the project files but I cannot spot anything that has changed.

Any suggestions what could have happened to my project and how to resolve?

Comment: Find the last version which works fine and describe the exact change which reproduces the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally tracked my problem down to an aspect I was using to monitor long running method calls. I had changed the pointcut to include 'within(com.mydomain.domain..*)' which is where my Controller class resides. This appeared to stop my bespoke links from working, not entiring sure why. I hadn't intended this, I just wanted my pointcut to include all domain class methods but I'm happy to sacrifice that in order to get controller method actions working again.

I've resolved this issue by amending my pointcut.